# How to add conditional based href to a <a> tag in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have created a menu list, some menus having url and some have not. In case of a menu having url then only the href attribute shown otherwise only   tag.
I checked like below but it came href="#" in case of menu.Url empty.

```
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left">
    <ul class="main-navigation">
        @* Here we will load only top level menu *@
        <li class="hidepush" ng-repeat="menu in menus| filter:{ParentID : null} : true">
            <a ng-attr-href="{{#{{ menu.URL }} || ''}}"><span class="{{ menu.css }}"></span> {{menu.Name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Numerous ways to do this.... `ng-if` is one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with `ng-if` check:-

```
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left">
    <ul class="main-navigation">
        @* Here we will load only top level menu *@
        <li class="hidepush" ng-repeat="menu in menus| filter:{ParentID : null} : true">
            <a ng-if="!menu.URL"><span class="{{ menu.css }}"></span> {{menu.Name}}</a>
            <a ng-if="menu.URL" ng-attr-href="{{#{{ menu.URL }} || ''}}"><span class="{{ menu.css }}"></span> {{menu.Name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use expression here like: `variable ? true: false`

```
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left">
  <ul class="main-navigation">
    @* Here we will load only top level menu *@
    <li class="hidepush" ng-repeat="menu in menus| filter:{ParentID : null} : true">
        <a ng-attr-href="{{ menu.URL ? '#' + menu.URL : ''}}"><span class="{{ menu.css }}"></span> {{menu.Name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```